# Determine whether the following argument is valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Premises: $p → r, q → r$, and $q ∨ ¬r$ Argument: $¬p$

I understand the answer but am having problems understanding how to construct this statement ie $(p → r)∧(q → r)∧(q∨ ¬r)$ where does the argument $¬p$ come into the equation.

This is a honest question and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What happens in the case that $p$, $q$, and $r$ are all true?

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is true, then both $q$ and $r$ are true, which is not a problem at all. So, the argument is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am having problems understanding what is meant by the 'Argument $¬p$', how is the argument included in this question? Could you please add that to your answer?

Comment: An argument consists of a set of premises and a conclusion. So, actually, the question should have taken the form: *Argument:* **If** (Premises), **then** (conclusion). What was meant by "argument: $\lnot P$" is that they are arguing that $\lnot P$ is true, based on the aforementioned premises. I agree that the question is poorly worded, but this is what is meant by it.

Comment: Thank you, that does clarify things, that was my original assumption but needed this for specification. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $q\to r$ is equivalent to $r\vee\neg q.$